# Laravel Pusher Presence Channel Auth error

Tags: laravel, pusher

I'm trying to build a presence channel. But the auth string returned is not correct.

Here is the back end code:

```
class pusherController extends Controller
{

    protected $pusher;

    public function __construct(PusherManager $pusher)
    {
        $this->pusher = $pusher;
    }

    public function pusherPinyinAuth(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->user()) {
            $user = $request->user();
            $auth= $this->pusher->presence_auth($request->input('channel_name'),$request->input('socket_id'), $user->id, array('h'=>'user_info'));
            return response($auth);
        }
    }
}
```

Error message

```
Pusher : Error : {"type":"WebSocketError","error":{"type":"PusherError","data":{"code":null,"message":"Auth value for subscription to presence-5 is invalid: should be of format 'key:signature'"}}}
```

I guess the the error is caused by the additional ':' added before the auth string. But I manually remove that it still report the same error. Here is my string output:

```
{auth: ":8dacf362f8fe62bae42c33dfe5511d3d1c42144685d5843a6a6a8014490ed0f6",…}
```

I'm using the pusher bridge from [https://github.com/vinkla/pusher](https://github.com/vinkla/pusher.)

I'd like to try the official pusher-php-server, but after composer install, I don't know how to use it in my code. I want to know whether https://github.com/pusher/pusher-http-php have the same issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For me this was caused by the pusher key, secret and app_id values not being set correctly in production.

Comment: You have to make sure that your .env file on the server contains all necessary variables and that they are set correctly.

Comment: I am setting the valid credentials still facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I also face this same error

```
Pusher : Error : {"type":"WebSocketError","error":{"type":"PusherError","data":{"code":null,"message":"Auth value for subscription to presence-5 is invalid: should be of format 'key:signature'"}}}
```

I was able to resolve this by returning an array containing the user details in the **channel.php** file

see code sample below: **channel.php**

```
Broadcast::channel('request_channel', function ($user) {
    return  ['id' => $user->id, 'name' => $user->name];
});
```